# Change EditText to checkbox on button click in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button, android-checkbox

Actually i want to change edit text field to check box dynamically on a button click.

initially there is  a single button on screen , on clicking a dynamically edit-text is generated, on clicking again the button the edit text converted to checkbox;

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you rather use two view elements and show/hide the views.

For example:
Have a LinearLayout that contains 3 elements. The Elements that should be switched, should have the same layout parameters.

A Toggle, a checkbox and a EditTextView.
If the toggle is clicked switch the Visibility for both Views. This is done via mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) or mView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE).

Comment: but this is for only one case, i want to add as many as possible
(generate dynamically)

Comment: so you want to dynamically add views and change them? you could use an xml layout file for a "row" containing a visible edittext and an invisible checkbox. if you need another one, get the layoutinflater service from the activity and add a new row to your layout. then you can reuse the view.invisible and view. visible mechanism on all rows. EDIT: of course, you could alternatively generate your edittext and checkbox programmatically. but that needs more effort since you have to create the layoutparams in code.